# How to add an item in array to list of html?

Tags: javascript

```
const toDoForm = document.querySelector(".todo__form"),
      toDoInput = document.querySelector(".todo__input");

const toDoArray = [];

function addToDoList() {
    toDoForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        toDoArray.push(toDoInput.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    });  
}
```

I made a code to put an input value to an array, and i want to put it in the list of html. How do i do that?

Comment: you mean that you would like to display the values in your array?

Comment: Yes, i want to display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the elements from your array dynamically by building a string and insert the string into the element.

```js
const toDoArray = ["Max", "mortiz", "martin"];


function displayArrayInList(){
 
 let output = `<ul>`
 for(let i = 0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
     output += `<li>${toDoArray[i]}</li>`
 }
     output += `</ul>`
     
     document.getElementById('displayer').innerHTML = output;
}


displayArrayInList();
```

```html
<div id="displayer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i have to use list insead of table so can you tell me how to put in list, not in table?

Comment: Now it is as unordered list

Comment: Thank you so much, That's exactly what I wanted to know! :)